# Tabulator Cell datetime object - Need to Format

Tags: momentjs, tabulator

I am attempting to reformat a datetime value in a cell that contains TZ UTC data.  An example value is: 2019-12-09T14:50:47.000Z-0500

I need it to display as:
MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm:ssXM  - ex: 12/09/2019 02:50:47PM

Local time, of course.

I have tried reading the moment.js doc without success.  Here is a snippet I have attempted.  The table shows up with "blank rows."  If I remove the formatting, the data shows correctly but not with the date and time format I would like.

```
{title:"Last Submitted", field:"createdOn", sorter:"date", formatter:"datetime", formatterParams:{inputFormat:"YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss", outputFormat:"MM/DD/YYYY", invalidPlaceholder:"(Invalid date)"}},
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Ben

**UPDATE BASED ON ANSWER 12/26/2019**

Thank you again for responding.  However, this is perhaps an issue for the author of Tabulator since I copied the inputFormat and outputFormat verbatim into the column definition of a Tabulator component and it displays blank rows.  If I remove the column cell formatter (which is a wrapper around moment.js code), the list displays with the full timestamp (including UTC / zulu time).

ex: 
**2019-12-09T12:50:47.000Z-0500**

Expected result (either 24h or 12h format doesn't matter at this point - and I did try to remove the "A" for the AM/PM indicator)

Unfortunately, I cannot upload the code for this project since it makes internal WS calls for JSON results (which is another issue - Remote Pagination does not appear to be working.)

Here is the source code for the column:

```
{title:"Last Submitted", field:"createdOn", sorter:"date", formatter:"datetime", formatterParams:{inputFormat:"YYYY-MM-DD[T]HH:mm:ss.SSS[Z]Z", outputFormat:"MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm:ssA",invalidPlaceholder:"(Invalid date)"}},
```

As stated above, if I add the formatter, blank **table** appear and nothing else. If I remove the formatter all data is displayed including the unformatted date (well it's formatted in a way in which I nor my users will want).

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

[Image of Result with datetime formatter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ogdMG.png)

Answer (score 1):

With `momentjs` you can parse date if you know the format of an input string:

```
moment(inDate, inFormat);
```

For example:

```
moment('12-25-1995', 'MM-DD-YYYY');
```

In your case format of an input string is `YYYY-MM-DD[T]HH:mm:ss.SSS[Z]Z` - square brackets work as escape characters.

You can get formatted string from `moment` object with `.format` method:

```
moment().format(outFormat);
```

For example:

```
moment().format('MM-DD-YYYY');
```

In your case format of an output string is `MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm:ssA` - you can read more in [docs](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/)

You can see how both parsing and formatting work together in the snippet below:

```js
let inDate = '2019-12-09T14:50:47.000Z-0500',
    inFormat = 'YYYY-MM-DD[T]HH:mm:ss.SSS[Z]Z',
    outFormat = 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm:ssA',
    outDate = moment(inDate, inFormat).format(outFormat);

console.log(`In Date: ${inDate}`);
console.log(`Out Date: ${outDate}`);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  So Moment.js will not convert the hour portion from 24h format to standard with AM/PM?  The result shows 14:50:47PM (the PM being correct).  I was hoping for a result like:
12/09/2019 02:50:47PM

Comment: Just do `outFormat = 'MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm:ssA'`